# WELD-001410: The injection point has non-proxyable dependencies

Tags: jsf, proxy, cdi

I have two Managed Beans:

SessionBean:

```
@Named(value = "sessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

  private final Param param

  SessionBean(Param param) {
      this.param = param;
  }

}
```

and TypesBean:

```
@Named(value = "typesBean")
@RequestScoped
public class TypesBean {

  @Inject
  private SessionBean session;

}
```

The project builds, but does not deploy:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001410 The injection point [field] @Inject private com.example.TypesBean.session has non-proxyable dependencies. Please see server.log for more details.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the lack of an accessible no-args constructor on the SessionBean class.

One solution as the OP pointed out is:

> "The problem was in `final` methods of SessionBean. Removing `final`
>   and making methods just public - solve the problem. Sorry for wasting
>   your time. "

Or alternatively...

```
@Named(value = "sessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

  . . . //variables, setters, getters and other methods
  private final Param param

  public SessionBean(Param param) {
      this.param = param;
  }
  // no-args constructor used by CDI for proxying only 
  // but is subsequently replaced with an instance 
  // created using the above constructor. 
  protected SessionBean() {
     this(null);
  }
```

Comment: Or make `Param` a managed bean too and annotate c'tor with `@Inject`. See also e.g. https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_injection_points